# Python: How to create an object which in not conneced to data

Tags: python, scripting

Good day. How can I make an object in Blender such that it is not linked to any object data?

I am using animation nodes and would like to use the script subprogram to make create an variable number of curve objects whose data I will change dynamically at a latter time.

I also need to give all these data-less objects systematic names. How can I go about this?

Comment: Hello, in Blender all objects save for empties have to reference some kind of data. You can either use empty objects and initialize curve objects when needed, or use curve data with no associated geometry (`bpy.data.curves.new(name="whatever", type='CURVE')`)

Comment: Thank you Gorgious for your assistance.